# how to predicate search with Azure Maps and it return only matching Word suggestion

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-maps

I want to search Addresses with Azure Maps API. when i Search "Strand" it Should Return Only the Matching Address that Start With "Strand" Word Not other  irrelevant Address Search.

here is the Api Query I'm Using.

```
 https://atlas.microsoft.com/search/fuzzy/json?query={Query}&api-version=1.0&subscription-key={SubscriptionKey}&countrySet={Country}&language={Langugage}&minFuzzyLevel=3&maxFuzzyLevel=3
```

In {Query} Parameter I'm Passing "strand"  but it return not Relevant Result .
Accepted Result only that start with "Strand" Key word

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a partial query and not a full address or place, you should add `typeahead=true` to your query. This will tell the service to use predictive mode. If you want the query to have more local relevance, add the lat/lon values to the query, or `countrySet` parameter otherwise the query is performed on the global data set.

The results will not always start with the string you pass in.